# Site looks fine on Local Server but crashes horribly when uploaded

Tags: php, html, cross-browser

Here's the site I'm working on http://amaralondon.com/Keith/ammoura

If viewed from Chrome/FF/Safari it shows up exactly as expected. When I view it through my localhost using xampp it's fine on IE11 too, however when I use the URL above and view it on IE11 it looks more like Picasso came along and griefed my site to shreds. I have a feeling that there may be something/something missing that is causing the site to display so badly on IE and was wondering if any gurus out there might be able to help?

Cheers,

Keith

Comment: You should probably delete this question..

Answer (score 0):

Lol it's all good, was simply missing the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

tag... d'oh!

Comment: What does this tag do, btw?

Comment: It tells the browser to render the page as a specified version of IE, in this case 'edge' refers to the latest version